# Making contingency table

Tags: r

I'm having trouble with contingency table.

I want to convert that kind of table:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="Gatunek,Obecnosc,Lokalizacja,Frekwencja
Koń dziki,TAK,Polska,11
Koń dziki,NIE,Polska,14
Koń dziki,TAK,Kujawy,39
Koń dziki,NIE,Kujawy,31",header=TRUE)

#  Gatunek Obecnosc Lokalizacja Frekwencja
#Koń dziki      TAK      Polska         11
#Koń dziki      NIE      Polska         14
#Koń dziki      TAK      Kujawy         39
#Koń dziki      NIE      Kujawy         31
```

to this:

[image: table1]

Don't be afraid, it's just Polish language.
For that moment I only have table which look like this:

[image: table2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xtabs should do the trick:

```
x <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 1, 2), b = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), c = c(11, 14, 39, 31))
xtabs(c ~ a + b, data = x)

#   b
#a    a  b
#  1 11 39
#  2 14 31
```

Comment: `xtabs(Frekwencja ~ Lokalizacja + Obecnosc, data=dat)` specifically for this example

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do almost every combination, but not this one... Thanks.